# Configure JNDI properties in wildlfly 10.1

Tags: java, wildfly, jndi, rmi, jmx

In my application it is using port 1099 for JMX Service (jmx:rmi://jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi). Does anyone know how we can configure wildfly not to start this remote JNDI lookup service or any other way to stop listening to port 1099. Is there anyway we can configure JNDI properties in standalone config for wildfly 10.1?

My jmx, remoting and naming subsystem config as follows;

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <!--<remoting-connector/>-->
</subsystem>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <!--<remote-naming/>-->
</subsystem>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">
        <endpoint/>
        <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing port conflicts you can refer [the Wildfly Admin Guide - Configuring Interfaces and Ports](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Configuringinterfacesandports).
If you want to bind simple properties to JNDI, you can refer [Wildfly Documentation - Naming Subsystem Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Naming+Subsystem+Configuration)

For both you can tweak the standalone config xml file or use CLI commands.

Comment: I already tried those documentation and also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html. It will start whatever com.sun.management.jmxremote.port I defined in the system properties. But issue is still port 1099 also listening.

Comment: When starting Wildfly 10.1 with default standalone configuration, only TCP port 8080 (http), 8443 (HTTPS) and 9990 (HTTP management) is listening. The CLI command "/subsystem=jmx:read-resource(recursive=true)" says, that the remoting connector for jmx is using the management-endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

What is your JMX and remoting subsystem configurations ?
I think you should either use the management port or change your connector port there.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I attached my configuration in the question. I haven't define any port in standalone config. But I tried to set as system properties like set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/a:D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.4.Final.jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11091 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=11092 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"